# Access AWS SSM Port inside Docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, networking, port, aws-ssm

I try to access some AWS resources from inside a docker container. Therefore I have a PortForwarding SSM session running on the host and everything works fine when I try to access the resources via `localhost:<port>`.

However, inside of a docker container I cannot access these same resources via `172.17.0.1:<port>`. Host communication per se seems to work just fine, as I can communicate with a local web server via `172.17.0.1:8000`. Only the combination of SSM and docker seems to be a problem.

`nmap` inside of the container also shows the port as closed.

Is there any way to get the combination of SSM and docker up and running?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that what is happening is that AWS SSM is port forwarding to localhost and is bound to the loopback adaptor.

If I run aws ssm port forwarding, I am able to access the port on the localhost and not via my machine IP:Port.

So when docker tries to access the port via its own natted IP it is unable to connect to the port.
I have the same issue that I am trying to solve with miniKube. Since I am only able to access my ports via localhost on my system, minikube is unable to access my localports.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you try to connect to a webserver from your container host and this works, but when logged into the docker container itself you cannot reach it?

If this is what you meant, It could be related to the fact that containers have a different network interface from the host and thus different security groups. If the receiving server's security group is configured to allow traffic from the host, but not from the security group of the containers running on the host, it would be a possible explanation for what you experienced.

Comment: Not exactly. The ssm port forwarding Session targets an ALB. The problem seems that the connection between the container and session does not resolve locally, as the logs from the Session Manager does not show that a connection was accepted. The Webserver example should only Show that host communication per se works in the Container. Just not in combination with a SSM Session. The Webserver was started through `python - m http.server`.

Comment: I don't really understand the sentence: `However, inside of a docker container I cannot access these same resources via 172.17.0.1:<port>.` Can you maybe try to describe the problem in other words. I understand that you SSM to an EC2 host, when inside the VM you can connect to the 172..17.0.1 address.

Comment: Also, I understand that the port forwarding session on the host targets an ALB and that works. However if you try to set up port forwarding to the container using SSM it fails right? What command do you currently use to connect to the container using SSM?