# Can't reach port-forwarded service within docker

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, networking, portforwarding

I'm connecting to a remote DB with a port forward (with [AWS ssm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html#sessions-remote-port-forwarding), `AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost): aws ssm start-session --target i-XXXXX --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost --parameters '{"portNumber":["5432"],"localPortNumber":["5432"], "host":["XXXXX.rds.amazonaws.com"]}'`).

The connection locally works fine:

```
$ telnet localhost 5433
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

But if I try to reach it within docker, it doesn't work:

```
$ docker run --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway mikesplain/telnet host.docker.internal 5433
telnet: can't connect to remote host (172.17.0.1): Connection refused
```

I'm in a situation where **I can't use** `--network=host`.

Am I missing something here ?

Seems strongly related to [Access AWS SSM Port inside Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69222946/access-aws-ssm-port-inside-docker-container)

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `aws ssm ...` binds to `localhost` (127.0.0.1), which means **you cannot reach the port from anywhere other than the local system**.

I wasn't able to find any mechanism to change the bind address used by `aws ssm`, but we can set up a simple proxy to take care of things for us. Using socat, we could run (on the host) something like:

```
socat tcp-listen:5432,reuseaddr,fork,bind=172.17.0.1 tcp-connect:127.0.0.1:5432
```

Now connections from your container will hit the proxy, which is listening on the Docker bridge address, which will in turn proxy those packets to `localhost:5432`.